# Controllers in Rails do not "care" how requests are executed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was reading an article about Rails controllers, can you help me understand please what is meant by the following phrase:
"The best controller is Dilbert-esque: It gives orders without knowing (or caring) how it gets done."

Is it true, in your opinion?

If, for example, I am accessing the index page associated with the subjects controllers, I would define the index method in the subjects_controller.rb rigorously, so I am confused as to what they mean in the article, as I would have thought the opposite.

Any pointers, please?
Thank you and sorry if this is too interpretable. This is the original article: http://betterexplained.com/articles/intermediate-rails-understanding-models-views-and-controllers/

Comment: Along the lines of I want all the models that are red. so it says Model.where(color: 'red'). Not something like `Select models.* from models where color = 'red'`.  That level of caring I think  is what they are getting at. They don't care about the implementation details.

Answer (score 2):

This article is talking about MVC architecture. What's important to take away from an article like this is the fact that Rails is best written with Fat Models and Thin Controllers. This means that you want to have the bulk of your methods/functions in your Model and want to have calls to the functions from your controller. Index is a bad example since typically you're not going to have a lot going on in there.

Your controller for index will typically look something like this

```
def index
  @subjects = Subject.all
end
```

If you want to scope order for displaying your subjects though, you would do that in your model with a block as follows:

```
default_scope { order("id DESC") }
```

A less contrived example might look something like this: Say for example you have an app that accepts input, takes that input and tallies several counters based on what the user entered. Your controller might be named subject_tally and look like this:

```
def subject_tally
  @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  @subject.winnings += 1
  @subject.total_matches += 1
  @subject.win_percentage = @subject.winnings.to_f/@subject.total_matches
  redirect_to subjects_path
end
```

**THIS IS WRONG.** This is a very fat controller and easily moved to the Model where it *should* be.

If written properly it would look something like this:

subjects_controller.rb: (The Controller)

```
def subject_tally
  @subject = Subject.find(params[:id])
  @subject.subject_tally
  redirect_to subjects_path
end
```

subject.rb: (The Model)

```
def subject_tally
  self.winnings += 1
  self.total_matches += 1
  self.win_percentage =winnings.to_f/total_matches
end
```

So as you can see, you make only one call from the controller and it "doesn't care" what is actually going on in the backend. It's literally there to pass a value (in this case, the ID of the subject in question) and direct you to another page, in this case, the index.

Furthermore, if you'll notice, you don't need to add that pesky @subject everywhere in your model's subject_tally function... you can reference the attributes of the object just by using `self.winnings` where you're assigning to an attribute.  Ruby is smart enough to know the current subject the method applies to (since you called that function ON a subject from the controller) and in fact you don't even need the `self.` if you're just retrieving the attributes instead of assigning them... which is why we didn't need `self` before `winnings.to_f` or the last line's `total_matches`.

Very convenient, less code, less time, yay.

Comment: I think "fat models" and "thin controllers" is a bit of a simplification but it's a good "starter for 10" for new rails developers... the important message being controllers shouldn't be overloaded with code that belongs elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

> The best controller is Dilbert-esque: It gives orders without knowing
>   (or caring) how it gets done.

means that you should put less logic as you can in the controller,
the controller should only know **what to call** to get what it needs, and should **not know how to carry out** a certain action.

In the "Sandy Metz rules" for rails developers (http://robots.thoughtbot.com/sandi-metz-rules-for-developers), she says:

> Controllers can instantiate only one object. Therefore, views can only
>   know about one instance variable and views should only send messages
>   to that object

**only one object** could seem a bit extreme, but makes the idea about how much business logic (no logic) you should put in the controller.